# Excel 2007 VBA ApplyTheme Addin

Tags: excel, vba, themes

I am trying to set the workbook theme using VBA code.

ActiveWorkbook.ApplyTheme("C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\MyTheme.thmx")

This works but I don't know how to create a path to the "Document themes" folder which will for work all users?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user's application data folder using the `Environ` function:

```
Dim themeFolder As String
themeFolder = Environ("APPDATA") & "Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes"
```